# Form key doesnt change remains the same - resulting 403 forbidden error on few links magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, form-key, http-status-403

i have further investigated in my case and i have identified that the
form key generated is not generating new form key . instead it is using the same form key for all users and pages

www.smartcityfood.in

Is my website that is running since. 2015 December..

Recently few of my customers gave me a complaint that on the view cart page. They cant delete or click on account link on top

When they click they are getting a `403 forbidden error`

I did not have this problem before . I didnt make any changes to files of magento
All of a sudden am getting these errors

- Try a store of my site http://www.smartcityfood.in/seasons/
- Add items to cart
- Go to cart page http://www.smartcityfood.in/seasons/checkout/cart

Then try the option to delete or on the top right of page there is a account link icon

Its giving is `403 forbidden error`

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i have found the reason why this is happening

follow the screens 
screen 1:
[image]

screen2:
[image]

open the login link from the screen 1 then click login button as shown in screen copy the link of login button. it  is different from the login link from category or cart page which is

the  code  _X19fU0lEPVU,/

is being attached to urls i have no idea how this is happening please help me remove the malicious code being appended to my magento urls